# Windows 10 High Ram usage after Creators Update

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, performance, windows-10-v1703

I have a Windows 10 Pro, Intel i7 6700hq, 16GB Ram system. While from the beginning, my idle ram usage would have been around %5-15. The creators update installed itself to my computer about 2 weeks ago. Now even when there is no costly program is running, my RAM usage is always over %95. There is no freezing or stuttering in the computer, but the Task Manager fails to show why so much RAM is used, so I decided to ask here.

Is this usage normal when idle ? Is this some pre-allocation done by the new update for performance purposes (Maybe) ? Or Should I worry about malwares ? (I have licenced Kaspersky Total Security installed, Scanned with malwarebytes a couple of times).

As you can see below, the usage is nowhere near my RAM limit (all the programs not shown in the image doesn't even add up to 300)
[image]

Resource tracker did not help as well.

Comment: What is using the RAM? open the *Details* tab of *Task Manager* to view.

Comment: What other tools have you tried other than Task Manager which does a horrible job, and is the very last tool, I would use to perform memory benchmarking on a system.  "here is no freezing or stuttering in the computer" - This tells me Windows is using the memory for other uses, and by using it, it has absolutely no effect on your system performance.  Why exactly are you concerned?  Unused memory is useless, it cannot be stored away for the winter, I don't see the problem to be honest.

Comment: @Ramhound The problem is another process maybe maliciously occupying the RAM, or something I should be aware of is happening at the time. I just wish to know. Any recommendations are appreciated (softwares included). Actually computer did some freezing, but I failed to find out how these were relevant.

Comment: "The problem is another process maybe maliciously occupying the RAM, or something I should be aware of is happening at the time." - We both know you have more than 3 applications running. So your screenshot isn't really helpful.  Anyways, considering you indicated you have no performance problems, I don't understand your concern about a hypothetical malicious process that doesn't seem to even exist. "Any recommendations are appreciated (software included). Actually, computer did some freezing, but I failed to find out how these were relevant" - You know that will not be done here at Superuser

Comment: the picture is not helpful. Run [RAMMap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap) and post the picture from it.

Answer (score -1):

disable prefetch service and reboot, i just solved by that workaround ..
if that don`t help, change value in registry:
HKLM \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Control \ Session Manager \ Memory Management \ PrefetchParameters set to 4

Comment: Disabling prefetch is going to make the author's system slower, in its current state, performance isn' affected.  This is poor advice.

Comment: sure, but that is workaround until new update fix that.. :>

Comment: What update?  Your suggestion would still cause the author's system to be slower.